# Como depurar en api symfony - postman

Tags: php, symfony, postman

Trabajo con `Symfony` - `PHP`, `Postman` para hacer las pruebas

Ocupo el siguiente código

```
foreach($distributivosx as $distributivo =>$datos){
         var_dump(
             $distributivo, $datos 
         );
     }
```

Esto es lo que devuelvo `return new Response($html);`

En postman me da el siguiente error `Error: Maximum response size reached`

**Hay alguna manera de depurar código en una api?**

Answer (score 0):

Proba incrementando el *"Tamaño máximo de respuesta en MB"* (`Max response size in MB`) en la configuración de `Postman`, para esto tenes que:

- Hacer click ir a `Tools` (*[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]*)
- Luego seleccionar `Settings`
- En la solapa `General`, sección `Request`, buscar `Max response size in MB`

> Opción para limitar el tamaño de la respuesta (en Megabytes) que representa Postman. Si se excede el límite, Postman le informará que la respuesta recibida es grande (límite predeterminado: 50 MB) y le brindará opciones para aumentar el límite de tamaño o descargar la respuesta. Tenga en cuenta que generar respuestas grandes puede afectar el rendimiento de la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

<kbd>[Fuente](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/settings/#:%7E:text=Max%20response%20size%3A%20Option%20to,limit%20or%20download%20the%20response.)</kbd>

Comment: Ya la tengo en 100MB que es lo máximo de su capacidad y aún así no cabe la respuesta

Comment: Entonces, puede que el problema sea otra cosa. Usa `$text = var_export($variable, true);` y guarda en un archivo la salida.

Comment: Para esto me supongo tengo que crear un archivo y pasarle una ruta, si tienes un manual donde me pueda guiar sería genial

Comment: Podes usar [`fwrite`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php) y después con cualquier editor abris el archivo.